# Не подключается к локальному хосту через docker

Tags: nginx, docker-compose

Я начал изучать докер и сразу столкнулся с такой проблемой.
При попытке запустить контейнер nginx указав путь к статическим файлам где лежит просто index.html для проверки сервер выдает ошибку что нет доступа.
Вот код docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.0'

services:

  nginx:
    image: nginx
    ports:
      - 80:80
    volumes:
      - ./html:/usr/share/nginx/html
```

Вот ошибка выводимая в консоль:

```
    Recreating my_docker_nginx_1 ... done
Attaching to my_docker_nginx_1
nginx_1  | 2019/09/18 16:34:55 [error] 8#8: *1 "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
nginx_1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [18/Sep/2019:16:34:55 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.75 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

ОС: Fedora 30.
Может у меня блочит порт или что?
Помогите пожалуйста

Путь до папки /home/kokos/Programing/PHP/my_docker/html/
Параметры папки kokos:

```
drwxrwxrwx. 24 kokos kokos  4096 сен 19 15:52 kokos
```

Programing:

```
drwxrwxrwx. 4 kokos kokos 4096 сен 19 08:39  Programing
```

PHP:

```
drwxrwxrwx. 3 kokos kokos 4096 сен 19 15:35 PHP
```

my_docker:

```
drwxrwxrwx. 3 kokos kokos 4096 сен 18 20:33 my_docker
```

html:

```
drwxrwxrwx. 2 kokos docker 4096 сен 19 15:55 html
```

index.html:

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 kokos docker 280 сен 18 20:19 index.html
```

Ошибка все та же:

```
nginx_1  | 172.18.0.1 - - [19/Sep/2019:12:09:37 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 403 555 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/77.0.3865.75 Safari/537.36" "-"
nginx_1  | 2019/09/19 12:09:37 [error] 8#8: *1 "/usr/share/nginx/html/index.html" is forbidden (13: Permission denied), client: 172.18.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
```

Я отключил SELinux теперь при запуске контейнера получаю такую ошибку:

```
Starting my_docker_nginx_1 ... error

ERROR: for my_docker_nginx_1  Cannot start service nginx: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/50c6923dc3246a429278cf8c092b3884397d183d38338a0ae48dbca93b3eef18/merged: invalid argument

ERROR: for nginx  Cannot start service nginx: error creating overlay mount to /var/lib/docker/overlay2/50c6923dc3246a429278cf8c092b3884397d183d38338a0ae48dbca93b3eef18/merged: invalid argument
ERROR: Encountered errors while bringing up the project.
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98850/discussion-on-question-by-b4ldy-------docker).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Дело оказалось все в SELinux. Чтобы его отключить, нужно открыть файл /etc/selinux/config.

```
sudo vi /etc/selinux/config
```

И изменить значение SELINUX на disabled.

```
# This file controls the state of SELinux on the system.
# SELINUX= can take one of these three values:
#       enforcing - SELinux security policy is enforced.
#       permissive - SELinux prints warnings instead of enforcing.
#       disabled - No SELinux policy is loaded.
SELINUX=disabled
# SELINUXTYPE= can take one of these two values:
#       targeted - Targeted processes are protected,
#       mls - Multi Level Security protection.
SELINUXTYPE=targeted
```

После редактирования файла, перезапустить компьютер и проверить что значение находиться Disabled.

```
[kokos@localhost my_docker]$ /usr/sbin/getenforce
Disabled
```

После отключения, удалить все докер образы и запустить по новой. Все заработало! Спасибо всем кто помог)